# Angular 7 Row Grouping with Sorting

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have been looking at several examples of row grouping in angular. However, I have yet to find any that have inner groups that are sortable.

For example look at this page:

http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#row-grouping

I would like to be able to sort by name within the group.

ag-grid can do this, but the license is very expensive.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/

This seems like a good grouping example, however there is no sorting:
https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/grid/grouping/

This is a basic one without any libraries:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-row-grouping

This is what I started with:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mattable-with-groupheader?file=app/table-basic-example.html

I added a basic mat-sort module to it, however the problem is that it sorts the group name as well, and group integrity is lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope this helps you.

- Row grouping
- Row expand
- Header Column sort

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-row-grouping-expand-sort

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: Very helpful stackblitz. Minor bug to report. After expanding a row, if you expand another row the original expanded row loses its subRows but still remains group.expanded = true.

One way to fix is to set all other groups to not expanded during groupHeaderClick()

    this._allGroup.forEach((item, index) => {
        item.expanded = false;
      });